# How do you download files from gs cloud for tensorflow tutorials

Tags: google-cloud-storage, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to follow some of Tensorflow's tutorials. Specifically this one:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection

It has a step that uses files in Google cloud storage. That step fails. It seems I should be able to manually download that file(s). But I can't click on the URL. I've poked around in Google Cloud storage, but it appears it costs money and I can't seem to figure out how to "copy" that file(s) from someone else's cloud storage to mine.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gsutil command line tool

For example

```
gsutil cp gs://cloud-ml-data/img/openimage/csv/salads_ml_use.csv /tmp/
```

It may ask you to login first - just follow the commands that shows on screen.

For more details see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#gsutil

Answer (score 0):

For that example it does need login details. You can open the notebook on Google colabs and download as in the above:

```
! gsutil cp gs://cloud-ml-data/img/openimage/csv/salads_ml_use.csv /content/
```

Comment: The files in the .csv also in gs:// protocol, how to download them too?